# I need to make an external link display as a popup window on a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a medium article popup similar to this link (from their site also). I want to stay on the same site I'm on but when clicking the link rather than going to the url the article is from, i want that content to show as a popup window on my url

Answer (score 0):

you can use php onClick `window.open("page path");`
it will open the popup link in new window and your current page will stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use any popup appropriate to your site, use onClick event to call the modal and within the popup body use an iframe for the external link, this way the external link will load within your popup.

```
<div class="modal-body">   
   <iframe src="https://visitnepal2020.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```